# Repository fetching data only in some cases

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, aspnetboilerplate

I have a ASPNET Boilerplate project; the piece of code below is executed both from a service and from a background job

```
    private readonly IRepository<UserTeam> _userTeamsRepository;
    [...]
    public List<UserTeam> GetUsers(){
        var defaultUsers = _userTeamsRepository
            .GetAllIncluding(ut => ut.Team, ut => ut.User)
            .Where(ut => ut.Team.AlwaysIncluded)
            .ToList();
    }
```

It fetches the data from a join table `UserTeam` between the `Users` table and a `Teams` table (one `User` belongs to multiple `Teams`, in one `Team` there can be multiple `Users`).

As I said, the `GetUsers()` method is referenced both in a web service and in a background job.
Using a breakpoint I can see that when the method is called in the web service the returned list is full of `UserTeam` entities containing both the linked `Team` and `User` entities (which is what I want).

On the other hand, when it is called from the background job only the `Team` field is populated, while the`User` part is null.

It is a very strange problem because the piece of code is the same and the only different thing is the fact that it is called in different contexts of the same application.

Do you know anything that may be causing this issue?

Thank you

Comment: Are you using tenants? Or Global Filters with values sent per request? From a background thread you don't have access to per request information (such as tenant or other HttpContext related things). Also keep in mind, DbContext is and should be resolved as scoped service, this means one instance per request. A background service doesn't have that and is usually a singleton,making your context a singleton too and there you have to manage the lifetime of your DbContext yourself (resolve, operate on it, dispose it)

Comment: Hi @Tseng. Yes, my application is multitenant (I started from the base template, which is multitenant), though I'm only using one tenant.

So, to sum up, I'm not able to get the Users information because the background jobs are not multitenant, right? Better, they are singleton through all the tenants, so cannot set the right `User` to fetch.

What shall I do to solve this now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the [Tseng comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51493129/repository-fetching-data-only-in-some-cases?noredirect=1#comment89956821_51493129), the background job is cross tenant so it does not have access to the `User` table information.

I fixed this issue by fetching the `User` data before enqueuing the background job and passing the data to the input object of the job.

Answer (score 1):

You can explicitly set the current tenant with `AbpSession`

```
public class MyService
{
    private readonly IAbpSession _session;

    public MyService(IAbpSession session)
    {
        _session = session;
    }

    public void Test()
    {
        using (_session.Use(42, null))
        {
          var defaultUsers = _userTeamsRepository
            .GetAllIncluding(ut => ut.Team, ut => ut.User)
            .Where(ut => ut.Team.AlwaysIncluded)
            .ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As soon as I can I will try this solution